# Filtering inside groups in polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I'm new to Polars and need some advice from the experts. I have some working code but I've got to believe theres a faster and/or more elegant way to do this. I've got a large dataframe with columns cik(int), form(string) and period(date) of relevance here. Form can have value either '10-Q' or '10-K'. Each cik will have many rows of the 2 form types with different periods represented.
What I want to end up with is, for each cik group, only the most recent 10-Q remains and only the most recent 10 10-Ks remain. Of course if there are less than 10 10-K forms, all should remain.
Here's what I'm doing now (it works):

```
def filter_sub_for_11_rows_per_cik(df_):
    df = df_.sort('cik')
    # Keep only the last 10-Q
    q_filtered_df = df.group_by('cik').map_groups(
        lambda g:
        g.sort('period', descending=True).filter(pl.col('form').eq('10-Q')).head(1))
    # Keep the last up to 10 10-Ks
    k_filtered_df = df.group_by('cik').map_groups(
        lambda g:
        g.sort('period', descending=True)
        .filter(pl.col('form').eq('10-K'))
        .slice(0, min(10, g.filter(pl.col('form').eq('10-K')).shape[0]))
        )
    return pl.concat([q_filtered_df, k_filtered_df])
```

Comment: Can you give an example dataframe along with the output of the given function?

Comment: @ouroboros1 I don't think this is a duplicate as different filters should be applied depending on the group keys (*form*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To simplify the example, I consider a dataframe with 3 10-Q and 2 10-K entries for each of two values of *cik*. I'll filter for the 2 most recent 10-K rows and the most recent 10-Q row for each group defined by *cik*.

```py
import polars as pl
import datetime

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "cik": [0] * 5 + [1] * 5,
    "form": (["10-Q"] * 2 + ["10-K"] * 3) * 2,
    "period": [datetime.date(2021, 1, 1+day) for day in range(10)],
})
```

```
shape: (10, 3)
┌─────┬──────┬────────────┐
│ cik ┆ form ┆ period     │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---        │
│ i64 ┆ str  ┆ date       │
╞═════╪══════╪════════════╡
│ 0   ┆ 10-Q ┆ 2021-01-01 │
│ 0   ┆ 10-Q ┆ 2021-01-02 │
│ 0   ┆ 10-K ┆ 2021-01-03 │
│ 0   ┆ 10-K ┆ 2021-01-04 │
│ 0   ┆ 10-K ┆ 2021-01-05 │
│ 1   ┆ 10-Q ┆ 2021-01-06 │
│ 1   ┆ 10-Q ┆ 2021-01-07 │
│ 1   ┆ 10-K ┆ 2021-01-08 │
│ 1   ┆ 10-K ┆ 2021-01-09 │
│ 1   ┆ 10-K ┆ 2021-01-10 │
└─────┴──────┴────────────┘
```

To filter the dataframe for each group defined by *cik*, we can simply use `pl.DataFrame.filter` together with `pl.Expr.over` (to define the groups) as follows.

```py
(
    df
    .sort(by=["cik", "form", "period"], descending=[False, False, True])
    .filter(
        (
            ((pl.col("form") == "10-Q") & (pl.int_range(pl.len()) == 0)) |
            ((pl.col("form") == "10-K") & (pl.int_range(pl.len()) < 2))
        )
        .over("cik", "form")
    )
)
```

```
shape: (6, 3)
┌─────┬──────┬────────────┐
│ cik ┆ form ┆ period     │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---        │
│ i64 ┆ str  ┆ date       │
╞═════╪══════╪════════════╡
│ 0   ┆ 10-K ┆ 2021-01-05 │
│ 0   ┆ 10-K ┆ 2021-01-04 │
│ 0   ┆ 10-Q ┆ 2021-01-02 │
│ 1   ┆ 10-K ┆ 2021-01-10 │
│ 1   ┆ 10-K ┆ 2021-01-09 │
│ 1   ┆ 10-Q ┆ 2021-01-07 │
└─────┴──────┴────────────┘
```

**Explanation.**

1. We sort the DataFrame in descending order by *date* for each group defined by *cik* and *form*.
2. We filter the dataframe for rows with *form* being 10-K and the row index being less than 2 (0 or 1 - **with your data, you'd filter rows with row index less than 10**) or *form* being 10-K and the row index being 0, i.e. the most recent entry. We use `pl.Expr.over` to do this filtering separately for each group defined *cik* and *form* (to ensure the index is being reset properly for each form).

Comment: I verified that this produces the same output on my large dataframe as my previous code. It's going to take me a bit more study to figure out how this works, but it's very tidy.

Comment: It seems like there would be a way to use this to solve another associated problem - adding a column that contains the number of the 10-K item starting at 1 for the most recent. (10-Qs can all be set to 0 by initializing the whole column as 0 beforehand). I need to better understand what's happening here to add this